# В каких ситуация применять logging в Java web app?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, логирование

На данный момент я разрабатываю сайт с помощью Spring, Hibernate, Freemarker. Подскажите пожалуйста когда именно применять логгинг,в каких методах или классах, в контроллерах или в сервис шаре? Где это целесообразно делать? Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ)

Comment: другого ответа, кроме как: "Где душа пожелает" быть здесь не может.

Comment: Логи - ваш помощник при отладке. Чем больше логов - тем легче дебажить баги на продакшене. Так что имеет смысл обкладывать все логами, пока это не будет сказываться на производительности.

Comment: @Nofate Но в пост продакшене все логи нужно убирать?

Comment: Вопрос вообще слишком субъективный и его стоит закрыть. Я, например, люблю логать входные параметры и результат на всех сервисах и на контроллерах в DEBUG, начало и окончание каких-то внутренних обработок. Самые важные процессы - в INFO. Если что-то сломалось - в обработчике исключения писать в  ERROR и оборачивать в бизнес-исключение. Какие-то нештатные ситуации, которые были нормально обработаны - в WARN. В чьих-то проектах могут быть другие общепринятые практики по этому поводу.

Comment: Что такое пост-продакшен? Продакшен - это и так уже промышленная эксплуатация. Ваше приложение, обслуживающее реальных пользователей на *боевом* сервере.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ)